# Is there a way I can get icon for the native Photos app?

Tags: ios, icons

I need to build a tutorial page for my extension and I want to prepend icons to the labels (Share Button icon and Photos app icon). I have found a way to add Share Button icon but I don't know how I can add the Photos app icon using iOS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the template icons from Apple go to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html) site. **The camera icon** is included in this list.

BUT!

**Don't use Apple app icons, images, or screenshots in your designs.** Apple designs are copyrighted and can’t appear in your UI unless they are provided by the system.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html).